# Android: new View on ButtonClick

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

DISCLAIMER: I am completely new to android developement and that is why I don't really know how to search for what I need or how to correctly state my question so here is what I want to do:

I have a view of a list with a button to add a new entry to said list. If the button is pressed i want to go to another "window" where i can edit the new entry. How do i do that the right way? If I create a new activity i have 2 apps on the emulator and the button just crashes the app. I could make the different windows just visible or invisible depending on what should be displayed but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would recommend searching how to use LogCat to find and interpret crash errors, assuming you're using Android Studio.

That will help you correctly open a new activity(screen) to go to in your app.

And you also may be thinking of `AlertDialog` or making a custom `Dialog` as opposed to creating a new `Activity`.

Comment: a new `Dialog` is a very nice idea, thanks for that. So activity is the right thing to do for new screens/views/however to call that?